# How to add members as a group or mail list in MS Teams using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When using the add members to a Microsoft Teams, I have no problems if the payload I pass is an individual user.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0) mentions it can accept a `user`, `directoryObj` or another `group`. In fact, the example payload is:

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
}
```

I created a mailing list, which is essentially just a group or directory object (not quite sure on which of the two) and tried the same API but I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Only Users can be members of a Unified Group. paramName: Members, paramValue: , objectType: Microsoft.Online.DirectoryServices.Group",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "STRING_GOES_HERE",
      "date": "DATE_GOES_HERE"
    },
    "details": [
      {
        "target": "members",
        "code": "InvalidValue"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't think any part of my request is incorrect, running the directoryObjects subAPI (for the payload) returns the correct location which I can unpack members from, but I can't actually add the members inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is included in the documentation you referenced (in bold):

> You can add users or other groups. **Important: You can add only users to Office 365 Groups.**

You cannot add a Group to a Unified Group (aka Office 365 Group or Team). Only individual users can be members of these groups.

As to the difference between a group and a directory object, there isn't one. Every object within AAD is derived from a `directoryObject`. Think of a `directoryObject` like you would [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netframework-4.7.2) in .NET or [`java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) in Java. So a Group is a `directoryObject` and a User is a `directoryObject` but a Group is not a User.

Comment: Oh, so adding a Group is possible, but only if the Group type is essentially a User. I thought since a group could be a list of Users then it would be possible to add it as well. Thanks for the clarification.

Is there any way to bulk add Users then? I can update the question to reflect this

Comment: Just to clarify, you can only add _User_ objects to a Unified Group. You cannot make a Group a member of another Unified Group. As for adding Users, there isn't a "bulk add" endpoint. You'll need to make one call per User you want to add.